Perfect Pairing and induced Isomorphism
Given a vector space V,  the perfect pairing $$\Lambda^k V^\ast \times \Lambda^k V \rightarrow k,~ (\phi_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \phi_k, v_1\wedge\cdots \wedge v_k)\mapsto \det(\phi_i(v_j))$$
it is said to give rise the a isomorphism of $\Lambda^k V^\ast$ and $(\Lambda^k V)^\ast$.
I would have two questions:

why is $(\phi_i(v_j))$ even a linear function that one can take the determinant of
I understand that the natural pairing means that one can take the map $<-, \Lambda^k V^\ast>: \Lambda^k V \rightarrow k,$ but how would this imply a isomorphism between the dual of k-th exterior power and the k-th exterior power of the dual?



$(\phi_i(v_j))$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\phi_i(v_j)$.
If $\langle -,- \rangle \colon \bigwedge^k V^* \times \bigwedge^k V \to K$ is the perfect pairing, then, for each $x \in \bigwedge^k V^*$ we can consider the map $\langle x,-\rangle \colon \bigwedge^k V \to K$ that takes $y \in \bigwedge^k V$ to $\langle x,y \rangle$.
It is easy to prove that $\langle x,-\rangle$ is an element of $(\bigwedge^k V)^*$.
Now, the map
$$
\textstyle
\bigwedge^k V^* \to (\bigwedge^k V)^*
$$
which takes $x$ to $\langle x,- \rangle$ is the desired isomorphism.

